# How can I spell-check any text shown on google-chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, spell-check

Is there a way to have google-chrome (or Firefox) to spell-check the text that is shown on the browser page (not just any text fields, but *any* text on the page)?

Is that possible by default? Or do I have to install an extension? If so, which extension?

Comment: I don't know of any way to do this, other than to select and copy the whole page, then paste into a new HTML document in MS Word or LibreOffice Write or equivalent software with its own spell/grammar-checker.

Comment: @AFH: For some reasons I am not able to just copy the 'page source'. The actual text is not copied with it. The non-public webpage contains two iframes with embedded jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this extension: https://www.grammarly.com/

or

1. Launch Chrome browser, click on the vertical ellipses to open the menu and choose Settings from there. Alternatively, you can also type `chrome://settings` in the address bar and press Enter.
2. On the settings screen type "languages" in the search box to locate the language settings.
3. Click on "Language" to expand the options and then click on Add languages. Add Language for Spell Check in Chrome.
4. In the list that opens up, choose the languages that you want to add in Chrome browser. You can use the search box to find your languages. Click on the Add button to add those languages. Add Language for Spell Check in Chrome
5. Type `chrome://settings` in the address bar and press Enter. This will open the Chrome settings screen once again removing the filters applied by the search box.
6. In the search box, type spell checks to find spell check related settings.
7. Click on Spell Check to expand the options and toggle the spell check support for the languages displayed in the list. Add Language for Spell Check in Chrome

That's it. Now your Chrome browser is going to perform a spell check as you type in any of those languages.

*from https://www.trishtech.com/2017/07/add-new-spellcheck-languages-in-chrome-web-browser/*

Comment: This appears not to answer the question, as it shows how to set up spell-checking on _input_, not on _all text_, as the questioner wants.

Comment: The `grammarly` suggestion does not work. I installed the extension, changed text on the webpage, but it is not indicated as incorrect...

Comment: @Alex try to allow access to file URLs from the extensions manager and highlight the word you want to check.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the LanguageTool add-on from https://languagetool.org/#firefox_chrome, starting with version 2.1.0. Select any text and then either click the add-on icon in the browser's toolbar or the "Check spelling and grammar" in the context menu. (Disclosure: my company is the developer of that add-on)

Comment: This does not answer the question. Like the other answers so far, this works in text fields, not on page content/HTML.

Answer (score -1):

I finally found a work around that worked for me. 
I went to Settings → Advanced → Languages and

1. I added my language, English (United States)
2. I moved it to the top.
3. I deleted the default language (which was the default English)
4. ...and now I was able to turn on Spell Check

Comment: How does this relate to the original question?

Answer (score -1):

Either of these chrome extension will solve your problem.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/site-spell-developer/jipadcefpndjimmmnjkecfjbbigbaekd

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/spell-checker-for-chrome/jfpdnkkdgghlpdgldicfgnnnkhdfhocg?hl=en

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.